# Pseudo Element Not displaying in nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was playing around with a little nav menu and pseudo elements and I was wondering why the tiny light orange square I have created displays on the first child element but not the other elements when it is copied over and put in the nth-child(2).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#orangeNavBar {
  height: 45px;
  width: 627px;
  background-color: #E87966;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  height: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li:first-child::after {
  content: "";
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background: #F1BAAF;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 7.5px;
}
ul li:nth-child(2)::after {
  content: "";
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background: #F1BAAF;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 7.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="orangeNavBar">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>Company</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just remove the `:first-child` rule — that way, you’ll select all children?

Comment: so like this: ul li:nth-child(n+4)::after{} ??

Comment: No. Like this: `ul li::after`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
ul li:nth-child(2)::after
```

only selects the **second** item

You need

```
ul li:nth-child(n+2)::after
```

so **each** child *after* the first one is selected.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#orangeNavBar {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #E87966;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  height: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li:first-child::after {
  content: "";
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background: #F1BAAF;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 7.5px;
}
ul li:nth-child(n+2)::after {
  content: "";
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background: #F1BAAF;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 7.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="orangeNavBar">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>Company</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh!  Makes sense, thanks.  Will mark correct in 5min